# What is Skype's URL handler for making calls in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, url, handler, skype

Does anyone know what URL scheme Skype supports for making calls from other apps (that should launch Skype and place the call). Thanks

Answer (score 3):

See the Skype URIs page for information

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn745882.aspx

Comment: It did back in October 2009 when this answer was given. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This code helps you to make call from skype by using your skype credentials

```
<a href="skype:username?call"> Call </a>
```

Comment: As of August 2015, this page documents the URI scheme https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn745878.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To save everyone a click and long read:

Chats - `skype:participant1[;participant2;...participant9]?chat[&topic=topicString]`
Calls - `skype:participant1[;participant2;...participant9]?call[&topic=topicString]`
Video calls - `skype:participant1[;participant2;...participant9]?call&video=true`

Taken from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn745882.aspx